# Query two tables with one to many relationship

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using two Postgres tables that have a one to many relationship.  The primary table is called users and the other table is called files.

The users table has the following columns:

```
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
email VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(128) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
password_hash VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
```

The files table has the following columns:

```
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
title VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
url  VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
```

When I log into my app, I'm querying all the files to display by doing

```
cur.execute('SELECT * from files')
```

and when I want a specific users files I run

```
cur.execute('SELECT * from files where user_id = %i' % user_id)
```

For my query that fetches all the files, I'd like to adjust it so that I get the username associated with each file also. How should I tailor my execute statement to make that happen?

Comment: Are you asking how you should join together the tables and then query it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. I know this syntax would work with other dbms':

```
cur.execute('SELECT f.*, u.username from files as f, users as u where u.id = f.user_Id)
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly.  so `f.*` is pretty much saying query everything from the files table?

Comment: Yes that's it. All the 'as f' is doing is providing an alias for that table, which you can then use throughout your query. Glad I could help.

Comment: For my other query scenario where I have the user id available and want the user files and username, I tried adjusting your code to `cur.execute('SELECT f.*, u.username from files as f, users as u where u.id = %i AND f.user_id = %i' % (user_id, user_id))`.   It works but is this the best way to go about it?

Comment: Yes that works, but I think it is far better to do the following:

`cur.execute('SELECT f.*, u.username from files as f, users as u where u.id = f.user_id AND f.user_id = %i' % (user_id))`